# Using append with values contained in a list in Python

Tags: python

I've created a program that uses random numbers to generate successive values. I want to use append to create this as a list, rather than just to set the values. (It's just experimenting with .append and .remove and seeing how I can use it to add values to successive lists, really). Can someone recommend how I would do that? Here is what I have so far:

```
import random
stats = ["strength","dexterity","constitution","intelligence","wisdom",
         "charisma"]
strength = []
dexterity = []
constitution = []
intelligence = []
wisdom = []
charisma = []

random.seed(198421)

for i in stats:

    die_one = random.randint(1,6)
    die_two = random.randint(1,6)
    die_three = random.randint(1,6)
    die_four = random.randint(1,6)

    a = die_one
    b = die_two
    c = die_three
    d = die_four

    i.append(a+b+c+d)

print("Strength: "+ str(strength))
print("Dexterity: " + str(dexterity))
print("Constitution: "+ str(constitution))
print("Intelligence: "+ str(intelligence))
print("Wisdom: " + str(wisdom))
print("Charisma: " + str(charisma))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to append one single value (the sum of four dice) to each list?

Comment: The thing going wrong here is that `i` is a string and you cannot append to a string

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following solution to your problem:

```
import random
stats = ["strength","dexterity","constitution","intelligence","wisdom",
        "charisma"]
your_stats = {}

random.seed(198421)

for stat in stats:

    die_one = random.randint(1,6)
    die_two = random.randint(1,6)
    die_three = random.randint(1,6)
    die_four = random.randint(1,6)

    your_stats[stat] = die_one + die_two + die_three + die_four

for key, value in your_stats.items():
    print(f"Your {key} is {value} !")
```

What you're effectively trying to do is assign a value to a key, or a stat. This is perfect for dictionaries. In dictionaries, you can easily 'get' your stat by the key. Give it a try!

Comment: Agreed with using dictionaries in this case, however I think the question is also about using `append`, here it is not clear how to append to your dictionary (in case you want more values for strength)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution for this is to use a dictionary:

```
di = {'strength': [], 'dexterity': [], 'constitution': [], 'intelligence': [], 'wisdom': [], 'charisma': []}
```

and then apply your for loop with throwing dice:

```
random.seed(198421)

for i in stats:

    die_one = random.randint(1,6)
    die_two = random.randint(1,6)
    die_three = random.randint(1,6)
    die_four = random.randint(1,6)

    a = die_one
    b = die_two
    c = die_three
    d = die_four

    di[i].append(a+b+c+d)

print("Strength: "+ str(di['strength']))
print("Dexterity: " + str(di['dexterity']))
print("Constitution: "+ str(di['constitution']))
print("Intelligence: "+ str(di['intelligence']))
print("Wisdom: " + str(di['wisdom']))
print("Charisma: " + str(di['charisma']))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First, in your for-loop, you are assigning dice values to some random values, and then you assign these new values to other variables such as `a`, `b`, etc. While you may do it, it does not achieve anything new.

That being said, you are also appending the number to a string `i`, which is not possible. What you want to do is use the lists you created above, such as:

```py
strength = []

# Your code for the random dice is fine :)

strength.append(a+b+c+d)
```

Once your lists are filled, you can visualize them like this. Note that the stat lists are now single-element lists:

```py
print(f"Strength: {strength[0]}")
```

That uses the lists, as you intended to in your question. That being said, for this problem, using dictionaries in this case is a good way to go :)

Comment: This is great. Would I use a similar way to pull a random element from a list and append it to another list? Say...

shopping = ["Chicken", "Cheese", "Milk, "Bread"]

shopping_add = shopping[random.randint(1,len(shopping))]

shopping.append(shopping_add)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random
import pandas as pd

stat_names = ["strength","dexterity","constitution","intelligence","wisdom","charisma"]
stat_values = []

random.seed(198421)

for i in range(len(stat_names)):
    dice = [random.randint(0,6) for i in range(4)]
    stat_values.append(sum(dice))

print(pd.Series(stat_values, index=stat_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dictionary data type will be more suitable,
and here is an example:

```
import random

stats = {"strength": 0, "dexterity": 0, "constitution": 0, "intelligence": 0, "wisdom": 0, "charisma": 0}
random.seed(198421)

for i in stats:
 die_one = random.randint(1,6)
 die_two = random.randint(1,6)
 die_three = random.randint(1,6)
 die_four = random.randint(1,6)
 a = die_one
 b = die_two
 c = die_three
 d = die_four
 stats[i] = a+b+c+d

print("Strength: "+ str(stats['strength']))
print("Dexterity: " + str(stats['dexterity']))
print("Constitution: "+ str(stats['constitution']))
print("Intelligence: "+ str(stats['intelligence']))
print("Wisdom: " + str(stats['wisdom']))
print("Charisma: " + str(stats['charisma']))
```

Hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different data structure to solve your problem. This is my  approach using a dictionary:

```
import random

stats = {"Strength": "", "Dexterity": "", "Constitution": "", "Intelligence": "", "Wisdom": "", "Charisma": ""}

random.seed(198421)

for key in stats:

    die_one = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_two = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_three = random.randint(1, 6)
    die_four = random.randint(1, 6)

    a = die_one
    b = die_two
    c = die_three
    d = die_four

    stats[key] = a + b + c + d

for key in stats:
    print("%s: %s" % (key, stats[key]))
```

The output will look like this

```
Strength: 18
Dexterity: 12
Constitution: 6
Intelligence: 12
Wisdom: 21
Charisma: 6
```